# Connect two entities in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rails-activerecord

I've got two entities: Issue and Project and I need to connect them together. 
In model/issue.rb I've got:

```
class Issue < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :estimate, :label, :status, :title
   belongs_to :project
   validates :title, :presence => true
   validates :estimate, :numericality => {:greater_than_or_equal_to => 0.1}
end
```

and in model/project.rb:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :title
   has_many :issues, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

And now, I need to create issue under some (selected) project. I know project id, but I don't know it in issue controller. Can you tell me, what should I do? Do I need some new migrations or controllers? Thanks

EDIT

Ruby 1.8.7

Rails 1.9.3

Rake 0.9.2.2

I made new migration:

```
def self.up
add_column :issues, :project_id, :integer, :null => false
end
```

but there is no project_id column in issues table.

Comment: do you mean that you want to have some sort of nested form under project to be able to create issues for a specific project?

Comment: Yes. I need list of issues for specific project and in some corner link or button to form to create issue.

Answer (score 0):

See

> http://gowithfoss.wordpress.com/2012/02/23/create-nested-form-in-rails-3-1

/ this should help you.

It's gem nested form that will solve your problem